# "File has been damaged and can't be opened": Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, file, windows-phone-8.1, isolatedstorage

[image]

I am writing files to isolated storage and trying to launch it but getting exception
like this:

```
"File has been damaged and can't be opened."
```

See my code:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.OpenReadAsync(uri);
wc.OpenReadCompleted += wc_OpenReadCompleted;

async void wc_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{

byte[] buffer = new byte[e.Result.Length];
await e.Result.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

using (IsolatedStorageFile storageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = storageFile.OpenFile("Document.docx", FileMode.Create))
    {
       await stream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }
}

StorageFolder local = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFile pdffile = await local.GetFileAsync("Document.docx");

await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(pdffile);

}
```

Comment: Maybe .Close() the stream before you try to launch it?

Comment: No maybe about it. :)

Comment: You didn't post any code that calls `IsolatedStream.Length`.

Comment: I suggest you tell us exactly where the "isolatedtream.length [sic] getting exception" occurs, preferably with the stack trace from the exception, along with the actual name of the exception. You still don't seem to have posted any code that accesses a `Length` property on a stream object.

Comment: What "stream.length"? There's nothing like that in the code you posted. How can you even access the `stream` variable on the `LaunchFileAsync()` method call? It's out of scope by then.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I know about it, but I am trying to check my "IsolatedStream", in debug, when I move my cursor to "stream", its length getting exception. That is why I am unable to open document

Comment: @PeterDuniho hello brother, see that screen shot. Can you help me about it?

Comment: Please stick to the code you actually want to run. It's possible to do all kinds of bad/weird/crazy things in the debugger, some of which will work fine, others of which won't. Checking the Length property of a Stream object after it's been disposed is going to throw an exception, but that has nothing to do with the code you posted.

Comment: Just call `await FlushAsync(); stream.Close()` after this `await stream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);` line

Comment: @Mihir thank you brother, but now I am getting new error. I try to open document with office in my windows phone 8.1, but can't opening. see my screen shot.

Comment: @PeterDuniho hello borther,are you there? please figure it out and help me,please!!

Comment: Where is this code executed? What's `e`? Is this in response to a HTTP request or something? Maybe the data you're being sent is corrupted or you're not interpreting it correctly.

Comment: @DecadeMoon yes, its callBack method result, openreadCompleted. thanks

Comment: @DecadeMoon I am just using OpenreadAsync() method, can you show me what is wrong?Thanks

Comment: I can't really help without knowing more about your code, what file you're retrieving and where it's from. I can only suggest to try a simpler task like transferring a .txt file and dumping the `e.Result` stream contents to the console to see if it contains the expected data. You should probably also check if `e.Error == null && !e.Cancelled` before touching `e.Result`. Any particular reason why you're not using `Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient` instead?

Comment: @DecadeMoon see my edit and I am calling URI using OpenReadAsync method, by the way I am not getting error in e.Result. Thanks

Comment: I still can't help any more than before. Your problem may not lie in the function you provided.

Comment: @DecadeMoon actually, what is wrong with it? I also getting not the proper reason, I am able to launch "txt" files using launcher.launchUriAsync("URL").

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63924/discussion-between-nitesh-kothari-and-decade-moon).

Answer (score 1):

You need to close the original `stream` before you can re-open the file for the call to `LaunchFileAsync()`.

Comment: Peter, but if I try to close it, I am getting exception like this, "System.ObjectDisposedException".

Comment: Where do you close it? When do you get that exception? Your question is incomplete without those details.